# Hot to fix update using join not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

MySQL / InnoDB

I want to fill `language_id` of table `country` as:

```
id name      language language_id
1  USA       English  1
2  France    French   2
3  Indonesia NULL     NULL
```

From:

```
language

    id name
    1  English
    2  French
```

Right now `country.language_id` has no values, which I want to fill from `language` table

The country which has no language name (Indonesia), its `country.language_id` can be 0 or NULL

SQL:

```
UPDATE country
SET language_id = language.id,  
FROM country
INNER JOIN language ON country.language = language.name
```

Its not working.

After setting `country.language_id`, I will delete `country.language` column and create foreign key relationship on `country.language_id` and `language.language_id`

Comment: The published code looks like sql-server. Multi table update syntax is different in mysql see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can try to use `OUTER JOIN` for that [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) statement, and the statement might need to use `JOIN` before `SET` in MySQL

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET assignment_list
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

so we might use as below.

```
UPDATE country
LEFT JOIN language ON country.language = language.name
SET country.language_id = language.id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=32178eabb73496c0f32efa79767eca83)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `LEFT JOIN` in your update query like so:

```sql
UPDATE country c
LEFT JOIN language l ON c.language = l.name
SET language_id = l.id;
```

[DB FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f024eb302800f2ef66d65a8b708631a0)